# Trouble installing libbz2-dev on Raspbian Buster

Tags: raspbian

I have been trying to install ROS Kinetic for my Raspberry Pi 3 for the past few weeks, but have been encountering numerous problems. The most recent problem is that I am trying to build my catkin workspace, but I found that the error is occurring with Cmake. It kept giving me an error message detailing about how it can't find bzip2. After some research, I figured that I needed to install libbz2-dev in order to create the header files necessary for Cmake to recognize bzip2.

But when I try to run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

It returns this message:

```
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf bzip2-doc all 1.0.6-9
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libbz2-dev armhf 1.0.6-9
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/b/bzip2/bzip2-doc_1.0.6-9_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/b/bzip2/libbz2-dev_1.0.6-9_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I cannot find any resources anywhere to help me understand why the links aren't working, so I am posting here for help. Please let me know if I need to provide any other information.

Answer (score 2):

Both files are present with suffix `1.0.6-9.1` instead of `1.0.6-9`:

http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/b/bzip2/bzip2-doc_1.0.6-9.1_all.deb
http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/b/bzip2/libbz2-dev_1.0.6-9.1_armhf.deb

You can browse the folder here:

http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/b/bzip2/

It seems that your package index is not up-to-date, just as the error message suggests. Please try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

Comment: I had already run apt-get update before to make sure, but it seems like the index is not working for the packages even though its up to date. I fixed it by manually downloading the files, transferring the files to the Pi, and unpacking them using dpkg. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and when I ran `apt-get update` it would give warnings like:

```
E: Repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' 
  changed its 'Suite' value from 'testing' to 'stable'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. 
  See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

fixing that, by running `apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change` as suggested here https://superuser.com/questions/1456989/how-to-configure-apt-in-debian-buster-after-release seemed to fix my libbz2-dev installing issues as well.

Comment: I wish I could mark both answers as the answer. I tried using the solution and it worked! Thank you.